# Spring integration (Manual Acking)

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-integration-dsl

I want to create a simple IntegrationFlow with Spring integration, and I am having difficulties.

I want to create an integration flow that takes messages from a queue in Rabbit Mq and posts the messages to an endpoint Rest.  I want to `ack` manually depending on the results of the post that I will make.

A typical behavior of the integration Flow would be like this:

1. I receive a message in the queue.
2. Spring detects it, takes the message and posts it in the Rest endpoint.
3. The end point responds with a 200 code.
4. Spring integration ack the message.

If the endpoint responds with an error code I want to be able to nack or retry.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
container.setQueueNames(BOUTIQUE_QUEUE_NAME);

/* Get Message from RabbitMQ */
return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(container)) 
    .handle(msg ->
    {
        String msgString = new String((byte[]) msg.getPayload(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        HttpEntity<String> requestBody = new HttpEntity<String>(msgString, headers);
        restTemplate.postForObject(ENDPOINT_LOCAL_URL, requestBody, String.class);
        System.out.println(msgString);
    })
    .get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use manual acknowledge mode for this use case; if he rest call returns normally, the container will ack the message; if an exception is thrown, the container will nack the message and it will be redelivered.

If you use manual acks, the `Channel` and `deliveryTag` are available in the `AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL` and `AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG` message headers and you can call `basicAck` or `basicReject` on the channel (you will have to add an error channel to the inbound adapter to handle errors.

Comment: how can i acess to the channel and deliveryTag in the middle of the flow builder ?

Comment: in tha `.handle(...)` - `msg.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL, Channel.class).basicAck(msg.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG, Long.class))`

Comment: Thank you Gary for your time !